# MongoDB geospatial query - distance calculation

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, geospatial

I have imported restaurant dataset available at 
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/brianboyko/DigiQuiz/master/primer-dataset.json

Mongo Query as below -

```
db.restaurants.aggregate([{
    $geoNear: {
        near:{ type: "Point", coordinates: [ -73.9243061, 40.8276297] }, 
        distanceField: "distance",
        maxDistance: 60,
        num: 5,
        spherical: true
        }},
    {$match: {"borough": "Bronx"}}
]);
```

**Output**

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("596613f776bc5df662633887"),
    "address" : {
        "building" : "860",
        "coord" : [ 
            -73.9249324, 
            40.8274822
        ],
        "street" : "Gerard Avenue",
        "zipcode" : "10451"
    },
    "borough" : "Bronx",
    "name" : "Us Fried Chicken",
    "restaurant_id" : "41713384",
    "distance" : 55.2511788230297
}
```

So I have basic question:
what is the unit of maxDistance specified in query & what is unit of distance field in output json.

When I check distance between these two points [ -73.9243061, 40.8276297] & [ -73.9249324, 40.8274822], it says 70 meters.

Thanks
Pari

Comment: It's in meters for GeoJSON. Error is common and is represented differently in different implementations. The curvature of the earth is not actually "exact". So some sources may have more accurate information, and some "libaries" use the math to the nearest approximation. That's why you see a difference.

Comment: Thanks. But my source data is not in GeoJson format -         "coord" : [    -73.9249324, 40.8274822 ], still I am getting in approx meters.